# Why can't I connect to the database?

Tags: heroku, ruby-on-rails-5

When I run `heroku run rails db:migrate`, I get an error:

```
PG::ConnectionBad: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
  Is the server running locally and accepting
  connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/pg-1.1.4/lib/pg.rb:56:in `initialize'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/pg-1.1.4/lib/pg.rb:56:in `new'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/pg-1.1.4/lib/pg.rb:56:in `connect'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:692:in `connect'
```

I have installed the `pg` gem. The is my config:

```
# database.yml
production:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  # For details on connection pooling, see Rails configuration guide
  # http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#database-pooling
  pool: <%= ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 } %>
  timeout: 5000
  database: bigbig-fishfish_production
  username: bigbig-fishfish
  password: <%= ENV['MYAPP_DATABASE_PASSWORD'] %>
```

Is there anything that I'm doing that's obviously wrong? Why am I getting the error?

Answer (score 0):

You aren't providing a `host` so Rails is trying to connect to Postgres running locally. Your database server won't be on `localhost` on Heroku. Also, your database name and username don't look right. You don't get to pick these values yourself.

Assuming you're using [Heroku's own Postgres service](https://devcenter.heroku.com/categories/heroku-postgres) you should be using the [`DATABASE_URL` environment variable](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql#designating-a-primary-database) to connect to Postgres. Since you're using Rails 5 you should probably [omit the `database`, `username`, and `password` values completely](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails-database-connection-behavior#configuring-connections-in-rails-4-1). Make sure you have a `DATABASE_URL` (you should have one out of the box if you're using Heroku Postgres) and Rails should use it automatically.